# Sinatra is using Thin instead of Puma

Tags: ruby, sinatra, thin, puma

I'm building a Sinatra application that needs to be threadable, as I'm using sucker-punch for jobs, and I want to use the Puma server to do it though I've never used it before.

For some reason, when I start my application it runs Thin.

I uninstalled Thin and it uses Puma, which is good, but how do I stop it from starting with Thin in the future in the case this happens again?

I start my application with `rackup` and I have in my main app.rb file:

```
class App < ::Sinatra::Base
  configure  do
    set :show_exceptions, true
    set :root, Info[:root]
    set :threaded, true

    set :server, :puma
    Tilt.register Tilt::ERBTemplate, 'html.erb'

    enable :logging
    use Rack::CommonLogger, Log.file

    if ENV['APP_ENVIRONMENT'] == 'PROD'
      set :environment, :production
      set :bind, '0.0.0.0', HOST
      set :show_exceptions, false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set your server in the `config.ru` rackup file. In this file you can set

```
Rack::Handler.get('puma').run App.new
```

Documentation is available in "[Module: Rack::Handler](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/Rack/Handler)".

However an even better way is to just run Puma explicitly:

```
bundle exec puma config.ru
```

OR as suggested by @matt:

```
rackup -s puma
```

Comment: You are starting your server with `rackup`, therefore you need to set the server type there. If you were to start the server by just running `ruby app.rb`, then Sinatra will run first and choose the server.

Comment: AH! I see, well know I'll know for future reference.

Comment: Putting `Rack::Handler::pick(['puma']).run` into the `config.ru` isn’t the right way to do this. It’ll sort of work, but you’ll get an exception every time you stop the server (as you don’t specify an app for the actual config) and any middleware you specify in `config.ru` won’t work. I don’t think the Rack DSL has a way to specify which server to use, instead use the `-s` option of the `rackup` command: `rackup -s puma` (or call `puma` directly as you suggest).

Comment: Thx for the comment @matt. Added your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Just run it with `bundle exec`. That ensures the gems available are only the ones specified on your Gemfile.

So, even if you have thin installed, but you have puma on your Gemfile, it will pick puma.

Comment: Even better, run `bundle install --binstubs --path vendor` and that sandboxes each projects gems to that particular directory. Then using `bundle exec` is extra safe!